# Two wired connection at the same time

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I am struggling with a network problem. 
My computer needs to be linked to two differents networks. one via PCI the other one via a USB adapter. The pci is the "usual" network, the usb is to use for specific address.
I have tried differents solutions, with dns, multiple wired connection, modifiying /etc/network/interfaces, ...
But I can't manage to have the 2 networking working at the same time.

Do you have any solution. I am working with Debian - jessie.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't specified any networks, IP addresses or device names, I will use my machine as an example.

I have an IOGear ethernet USB dongle which shows up as device **enx0050b6d341bb**, and an RTL811 PCI ethernet device which shows up as **eth0**. eth0 is plugged into the "main" network which has a DHCP server and enx0050b6d341bb is connected to a private switch on my workbench.

If I want to use eth0 to connect to the internet, but use enx0050b6d341bb to connect to anything on network 192.168.168.0/24, /etc/network/interfaces will look like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Obtain DHCP address from server
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# Connect to 192.168.168.0 network
auto enx0050b6d341bb
iface enx0050b6d341bb inet static
    address 192.168.168.3
    network 192.168.168.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Since I only have one device using DHCP, my default route will automatically go through that device, which happens to be exactly what I want :-)

```
solargy@GEPY633007AX:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0 
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.67 
192.168.168.0/24 dev enx0050b6d341bb  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.168.3
```

The above shows that my default traffic will go through eth0 and that any traffic for addresses in network 192.168.168.0/24 will go through enx0050b6d341bb. To verify that, you can find out which device will be used to communicate with address 192.168.168.2:

```
solargy@GEPY633007AX:~$ ip route get 192.168.168.2
192.168.168.2 dev enx0050b6d341bb  src 192.168.168.3 
    cache
```

As you can see, any traffic for 192.168.168.2 will go through enx0050b6d341bb.